# Get list of all header files inclusion for every file in the project

Tags: c++, gcc, header, include, g++

I need to see all includes from every file, just -H without filename gives me headers names, but I don't understand what file is including them, and that is what want.

I also tried -M with -MF, but in log-file I have information only about one .o

Answer (score 0):

`gcc -H somefile.c` shows the files included by `somefile.c`, indenting according to the nested `#include`s. About why each file is including the specific header, you'd have to ask the programmer.